# How to add validation if CRUD operation is done with routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-validation

I wanted to ask for your help about how I can add validation to forms if routes are used rather than controllers. The code I use so far:

```
Route::post('/contact/submit', function (Request $request) {
    validate($request,[
        'FirstName'=>'required',
        'LastName'=>'required',
        'Age'=>'required'
    ]);
```

Also, how is it possible to add custom validation, for example, to ensure that instead of message "Name is required" just show "Please fill name field".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to use `Validator` class and yes you can also add another variable for custom message.

```
Route::post('/contact/submit', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $rules = [
        'FirstName' => 'required',
        'LastName' => 'required',
    ];
    $messages = [
        "FirstName.required" => "First name is compulsory.",
        "LastName.required" => "Last name is mandadory.",
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules,$messages);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return dd($validator->messages());
    }
});
```

Error Message will be like

```
MessageBag {#1332 ▼
  #messages: array:2 [▼
    "FirstName" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "First name is compulsory."
    ]
    "LastName" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Last name is mandadory."
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

Comment: @2486,  thank you for your solution, so Validator is used with route i and validate is used with controller. Right? I hope for your answer

Comment: you can also use `$request->validate` function